# Cache emitted value for dependent observable but not source observable

Tags: rxjs, observable

I am currently implementing a new feature at work. The app wants to give sellers an admin where they can see various things. An example of one of the things they can see on their dashboard is their last 10 orders.

The order's API only returns an array of various ids (customer id, product id, seller id, etc) In order to populate the orders page, I have to make 3 different API call on each order to get the data to render on the order list page

Now that I have to create a dashboard that is different from the order list page, I do not want to make such a tedious API call again. I want to create a dashboard$ observable that has the last emitted value of orderList$ but I do not want anything subscribed to orderList$ to be cached.
So when orderList$ is called, it gets the lastest orderList data from the server (I do not feel something as sensitive as order list should be cached), when dashboard$ is called, get the last emitted value of orderList$ and if orderList$ has not emitted any values then dashboard$ can make a request to retrieve order list.

Answer (score 0):

When working with a reactive state of mind, I like to define what should happen based on events. By this I mean that I'll have a `Subject` in which in can push values into to notify an event and from there we can react to these events.

In your case, here's an idea for what you want:

```
const navigationToOrdersPage$$ = new Subject<void>();
const refreshOrdersButtonClicked$$ = new Subject<void>();

const orders$: Order[] = merge(
  navigationToOrdersPage$$,
  refreshOrdersButtonClicked$$
).pipe(
  switchMap(() => yourOrderService.getOrders()),
  shareReplay({
    bufferSize: 1,
    // make sure that even if we don't have anyone subscribed to that observable
    // we keep the result in the cache and if we ever go to the orders page or click
    // on the refresh button it'll be updated anyway but with this it's safe to navigate
    // to another page than orders and the dashboard and if you go back to the dashboard
    // you'd still get an instant result
    refCount: false,
  })
);
```

So here it'd be safe to reuse this observable on both the admin and the dashboard page. Of course, you'll need to call `next` on the 2 subjects when appropriate so that the orders can be refreshed when they need to.